# Ruby/Rails - Error with undefined method join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, join

I'm trying to loop through and match the following string:

```
@custom_channels = { cnn: 2, abc: 90 }
```

I then want to be able to check/match against each and return the channel number (e.g. 90):

```
listen_for /channel to (#{@custom_channels.join('|')})/i do |name|
    change_channel @custom_channels[name.downcase]
end
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
scraper.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `join' for {:cnn=>2, :abc=>90}:Hash (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Why do you use `join` here? What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking for:

```
@custom_channels = { cnn: 2, abc: 90 }

channel_names = @custom_channels.keys.map(&:to_s)

listen_for /channel to (#{Regexp.union(channel_names)})/i do |name|
    change_channel @custom_channels[name.to_sym]
end
```

Comment: Do you have a typo? `{cnn: 2, abc: 90}.keys #=> [:cnn, :abc] `

Comment: Do you have another typo? `Regexp.union([:cnn,:abc].map(&:to_s)) #=> /cnn|abc/`

Comment: I fixed this by adding: `#{Regexp.union({ cnn: 2, abc: 90 }}` it didn't like `@custom_channels.keys` in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
1.9.3p0 :007 >   channels = {:cnn=>2, :abc=>90}
 => {:cnn=>2, :abc=>90} 
1.9.3p0 :008 > channels.keys
 => [:cnn, :abc] 
1.9.3p0 :009 > channels.keys.each do |name|
1.9.3p0 :010 >     puts channels[name]
1.9.3p0 :011?>   end
2
90
 => [:cnn, :abc]
```

Comment: I need it to return the actual number not the text.

Comment: What is the actual number you expect?

Comment: If I ask for "cnn" I want to return: 2

Comment: Are you not able to modify it yourself?

Comment: `@custom_channels[:cnn] #=> 2`